# Can I ask about Keepcups here?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

Australian coffee shops have been taking to stocking their own [Keepcups](http://keepcup.com/) in recent years, often marked with the coffee shop's brand. For those unaware — I don't know what their presence is like outside Australia — this is a Melbourne-based company that produces reusable coffee cups in glass or plastic, like this one:

[image: a glass keepcup.]

I have some questions about my own keepcup and maintaining it. This isn't about coffee itself, but this is intimately a coffee product, and I'm going to find my expertise on keepcups within the coffee drinker world.

Do questions about Keepcups fit here, or not?

Comment: Incidentally, now that I've seen it, I _really_ want one of those things. Perfect for my piping hot morning americano.

Comment: These are popping up around London too!

Answer (score 6):

I would say yes, since they are intrinsically related to coffee, and would be a useful addition to a repository of coffee knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if you use it in conjunction with storing, brewing or consuming coffee - I think it's on-topic. I've got some porcelain stuff I'd *love* to get coffee stains out of, and intend to ask about that as soon as I find some time.